# How can I ensure a numpy array to be either a 2D row- or column vector?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a `numpy` function to ensure a 1D- or 2D- array to be either a column or row vector?

For example, I have either one of the following vectors/lists. What is the easiest way to convert any of the input into a column vector?

```
x1 = np.array(range(5))
x2 = x1[np.newaxis, :]
x3 = x1[:, np.newaxis]

def ensureCol1D(x):
    # The input is either a 0D list or 1D.
    assert(len(x.shape)==1 or (len(x.shape)==2 and 1 in x.shape))
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    n = x.size
    print(x.shape, n)
    return x if x.shape[0] == n else x.T

assert(ensureCol1D(x1).shape == (x1.size, 1))
assert(ensureCol1D(x2).shape == (x2.size, 1))
assert(ensureCol1D(x3).shape == (x3.size, 1))
```

Instead of writing my own function `ensureCol1D`, is there something similar already available in `numpy` that ensures a vector to be column?

Comment: Have you looked the code for `atleast_2d`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is essentially how to convert an array into a "column", a column being a 2D array with a row length of 1. This can be done with `ndarray.reshape(-1, 1)`.

This means that you `reshape` your array to have a row length of one, and let numpy infer the number of rows / column length.

```
x1 = np.array(range(5))
print(x1.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Output:

```
array([[0],
   [1],
   [2],
   [3],
   [4]])
```

You get the same output when reshaping `x2` and `x3`. Additionally this also works for n-dimensional arrays:

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 2, 3)
print(x.reshape(-1, 1).shape)
```

Output:

```
(6, 1)
```

Finally the only thing missing here is that you make some assertions to ensure that arrays that cannot be converted are not converted incorrectly. The main check you're making is that the number of non-one integers in the shape is less than or equal to one. This can be done with:

```
assert sum(i != 1 for i in x1.shape) <= 1
```

This check along with `.reshape` let's you apply your logic on all numpy arrays.

Comment: Perfect, this was what I was looking for. Thanks! :)